# expr is giving unexpected results

Tags: tcl

expr is giving unexpected results for 4 characters (t, n, f, y). And if you are doing some further calculation. then code is breaking. I could not understand why this is happening?

```
% expr (F)
F

% expr (F)*1
can't use non-numeric string as operand of "*"
```

And,

```
% expr (t)
t
% expr (n)
n
% expr (f)
f
% expr (y)
y
```

This is coming file for charcters : t, n, f, y. There are no variables named by these characters. It should flag variable not found or some other valid error. Am i missing some thing?

Comment: Which version of TCL are you using?

Comment: TCL version 8.5 Linuk platform

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
The [expr] conditions of commands such as [if] and [while] expect the expression to evaluate to a boolean, i.e., an integer or one of the following string values:

    true, on, yes
    false, off, no
```

I believe t, y, f and n are shortcuts for these.

Comment: You are surely right! I didn't noticed that using other strings, it gives an error. Indeed, `expr f ? 5 : 7` gives 7, while `expr y ? 5 : 7` gives 5

Comment: Unique prefixes of the boolean literals. (I may have been the one who put the code in but sometimes the results can be unexpected!)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are expecting something wrong from `expr`.

That command is intended for evaluating expressions. It can do arithmetical operations on number, compare strings or number, execute some mathematical functions, and such.

Your lines

```
% expr (F)
% expr (t)
% expr (n)
% expr (f)
% expr (y)
```

all do the same thing: they ask to perform **no** operation on a literal string with higher precedence (the braces). So? There is nothing more and `expr` returns the string itself.

In

```
% expr (F)*1
```

however, you are trying to multiply a *string* to a number: an operation which is not defined. Indeed, `expr` gives you an error saying that one of the operands of `*` is a non numeric string (which number `F` should represent?).

With a literal string such `F`, or `y`, you can ask *string comparison*. For example, you can do these:

```
% expr F < f
1
```

(because in my encoding the upper case letters come before lower case ones)

```
% expr F == y
0
```

and so on.

So, `expr` is not giving any unexpected result, but maybe your expectations are wrong.